# Created a user with permissions to one table, but unable to access the database that contains the table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, database-permissions

I've tried to create a Login that will have access to a single table from a few different databases.

When I try and query the table, using the created Login I get the following error:

> The server principal "log_Reader" is not able to access the database
>   "MyDB" under the current security context.

Here's the SQL I used to create the Login/User:

```
USE MASTER
GO

CREATE LOGIN log_Reader
WITH PASSWORD = '<password>'
GO



USE DB1
GO
CREATE USER log_Reader FOR LOGIN log_Reader
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.logtable TO log_Reader

USE DB2
GO
CREATE USER log_Reader FOR LOGIN log_Reader
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.logtable TO log_Reader

USE DB3
GO
CREATE USER log_Reader FOR LOGIN log_Reader
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.logtable TO log_Reader

USE DB4
GO
CREATE USER log_Reader FOR LOGIN log_Reader
GRANT SELECT ON dbo.logtable TO log_Reader
```

Does anyone have any ideas what I've missed ?

Thanks,
Jason

Comment: Does ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [log_Reader] help?

Comment: Its 2008 R2, so I tried sp_addrolemember to the role that you suggested - unfortunately, no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this to work.

It looks like the problem was the initial default schema when creating the User.

I dropped the Login and User and recreated with a default schema and it worked.